# sorted by name in sqlite what to return un numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: objective-c

i have sorted my data by name in sqlite:

```
     char*sql="SELECT* FROM tblcocktail ORDER BY drinkname ;";
```

i dont know how to show it in the table sorted by letters:
please advise :)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
Cocktails*cock=[[Cocktails alloc]init];
_arrcocktail=[cock getallcocktail];
[self.tableView reloadData];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 // Return the number of sections.
 return [_arr count]; //all the letters
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //i don't not what to put here so it will show me the right name under the right letter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create cells and assign names.

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: but i need the data to be sorted alphabetic

Comment: look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197842/iphone-how-to-use-core-data-in-an-already-created-program